# Why a crond can start late randomly

Tags: cron

I have this issue of a `cron` that executes a **PHP** script at ***minute 20 every hour***,

This script generates a small number of reports based on data from a MySql database.

Generally this script ends about ***minute 30 of the hour***, i.e., lasts 10 minutes,

But a few times it ended about minute **45**, even minute **50** of the hour,

So we set a log to see where was the delay. To our surprise we saw that some times the script didn't started at minute **20**, last time it delayed it started at minute **35** with no apparent reason.

We searched for locked tables in MySql but found nothing.

Have anyone any idea of what can be happening here to delay a `cron` script?

Comment: Does your script use a pid file? maybe it is starting late because it had to avoid stepping on itself. Depending on the script this could cause late start and stop times.

Comment: @Baazingar we're not using pid files for this script

Comment: Can you post the line you are using in the crontab?

Comment: This is the line: `20 9-23 * * * wget http://localhost/reports/my_script.php`

Comment: What distribution is this? Is anacron installed? Which logs did you look at?

Comment: I saw occasionally cron jobs delayed on systems affected by flakey NFS mounts, especially if the homedir of the user owning the cron job or the script invoked by the job is located on such NFS mount. Sometimes multiple repeated invocations of the same cron job were delayed and fired **simultaneously** at a later time. Typically the cron/crond syslog entries (in adition to job logs) can be used to differentiate between delays in launching of the cron job itself (which shouldn't be affected by any locks/pidfiles) or delays in launching/execution of the cmd/script invoked by the cron job.